# Modules to recompile if new fields are added to a Struct in a Header file

Tags: c, struct, compilation

There are 3 existing c modules , all of them calls(or uses) the below Struct declared in a header file ( ABC.h)

If I declare a new field inside the struct info called city[30] (4th field) and if this field is only used in the 3rd C module (Module3.c) and not in the other two modules (Module1.c and Module2.c) which only pass value to the other fields but do not refer info.city at all , do I need to compile Module1 and Module2.
Only codes that have changed are ABC.h and Module3.c which has a a new line of code --
Move 'CityName' to info.city;

```
//ABC.h -->
struct Info
{

    char  name [50];
    char  occupation [50];
    char  address [100];
    char  city [30]; //Newly added field

 }          info;

//Module1.c -->
Move 'fullname' to info.name;

//Module2.c -->
Move 'Job' to info.occupation;

//Module3.c -->
Move 'CityName' to 'info.city';
```

Comment: If you use `Info` in Module1.c, and the definition of `Info` has changed, you need to recompile Module1.c.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what makes you doubt that you need to recompile all modules which use an included  headers content if you change that content. To me it seems to be the concept of modules, headers and how/when to include and compile. I think that you constructed your code example specifically to illustrate what causes your doubt, but in order to address it helpfully in answers you should be more explicit. Then why it does not work as you assume (or not reliably in all cases) can be explained, with examples which demonstrate what can go wrong how.

Comment: You might also want to upgrade your code example to a [mre] which demonstrates why you think that what you describe might not be a problem.

Comment: It is not simple for this, when you adding new param, the total memory consumed by struct will change and will cause a lot of drawback. In case, you you really want to do this it is better to declare new struct in module3.c and explicit cast old struct to new by pointer. But for sure, there will be problem with the size of struct, need to make sure that new fields does not overlap others

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Yunnosch , Just to clarify I am new to C and have started working on an existing large codebase. The above code is just simplified to explain my query. Simply explaining , there is a struct defined in a header. Its variables are used in n number of C files where this struct is referenced. I am adding a new variable inside this struct which will only be used(or referenced) in 1 C module. So do I have to re-compile the other (n-1) C modules?

Comment: Please follow this link and read it. [mre] it is a widely used and well-tested concept to support making a question answerable. A description of your understanding of the code in the MRE is also very good, ideally as part of the question, instead of in a comment.